# How to adjust introjs-tooltip width using css

Tags: css, intro.js

How to make a specific introjs tooltip width longer? I'm able to change the text color using css but changing the width is not working.

CSS:

```
.customTooltip * {
    color: #4a4a4a;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.customTooltip .introjs-tooltip-title {
    color: #0a41c9;

}
//Not working
.customTooltip .introjs-tooltip {
    min-width: 500px;
}
```

IntroJs:

```
const intro = introJs();
intro.setOptions({
  steps: [{
      title: 'Title',
      intro: 'Long Intro',
      tooltipClass: 'customTooltip'
    }
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you want to resize the parent div?

you can try

```
.customTooltip {
  min-width: 500px;
}
```

directly, and your can add  `!important` too.